# Frozen Fruits Effectivenss?

Tags: freezing

I've got a variety of frozen fruits in a freezer that I've been neglecting...For 12 months or so, at this point. At this point I'm wondering whether I should bother with the fruit at all or if there's a receipe that works better with aged produce? Part of my stock is fruit that was already frozen and part were cranberries that started fresh and then got the freeze. Any tips?

Comment: See https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/21068/how-long-can-i-store-a-food-in-the-pantry-refrigerator-or-freezer

Comment: We can't give you suggestions for using them, since we are not a recipe sharing site.  I think the linked answer is the best we can do.

Answer (score 1):

I have used frozen fruits in syrups and smoothies after over a year in the freezer with good results. They will likely not keep their shape when they thaw, so something where you want a fruit puree will work best.